# Calculus BC--Continuity

Tags: calculus

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
 |x-3|+1, &  x<3 \\ 
ax^2 +bx, &  x \ge 3 
\end{cases}$$

Describe all values of $a$ and $b$ for which $g(x)$ is a continuous function (this should be an equation).

I have no problem solving problems like this with a single variable; however the two variables, a and b, are throwing me off and I don't know how to approach the problem.`

Comment: You just have to solve the equation at 3.

Comment: You can find a relation between $a$ and $b$ that must hold.

Comment: Hint: If $g(x)$ as continuous at $x=x_0,$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x)= g(x_0).$

Answer (score 2):

For $x <3$, $g (x)=-(x-3)+1=4-x $ thus

$$L^-=\lim_{x\to 3^-}g (x)=4-3=1$$

For $x>3$ , $g (x )=ax^2+bx $ thus
$$L^+=\lim_{x\to 3^+}g (x)=9a+3b$$

$$g (3)=9a+3b $$

$g $ is continuous at $\mathbb R-\{3\} $  as a polynom.
$g $ is continuous at $x=3 \iff $

$$L^-=L^+=g (3) $$
$$\iff 9a+3b=1$$

the equation of quadratic is then
$$\boxed {ax^2+(\frac {1}{3}-3a)x} $$

there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: So then what would the equation of the quadratic be to make he function continuous?

Comment: @VictorPacheco i just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\lim_{x \to 3^-} (|x-3|+1) = 1$ and since $x(ax+b)$ is defined at $3$ by definition, we need to find the solution $(3,1)$ for $a$ and $b$.

$$ 9a + 3b = 1 $$

Now you only have one equation and two unknowns, so this relation is as far as you can solve. You could express it all in terms of $a$ or $b$ if you'd like, i.e.

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}
|x-3|+1, & x < 3 \\
\left( \frac{1-3b}{9} \right)x^2-bx, & x \ge 3 \\
\end{cases} $$